# Meanings: "carriage," "by arrangement."

Tags: meaning-in-context

The complete sentence is as follows:

> All across the route I took, wheeled conveyances could be brought, supplies and water could be got, and **carriage** for large numbers **by arrangement.**

*carriage* and *by arrangement* are especially problematic.

Comment: carriage = transport/vehicles; by arrangement = not regular service but on request/contract. HTH.

Answer (score 1):

There is a word (a past participle) missing. The final clause should perhaps read:

*...and carriage, for large numbers, **made** by arrangement*.

**made**, could equally well be: *put in place*, *organised*, *set up*, etc.

Or you could say:

*...and large numbers carried by arrangement*.

The clause needs a verb somewhere since it is not clear which of the two previous verbs in the sentence, *brought* and *got*, might be applied to *carriage*, which in your example is a noun.

Comment: The comma goes **after** *made,* though.

Comment: @Kris No. I disagree. I have employed parenthetical commas. And the clause makes perfect grammatical sense without the words between commas.